# How can i count exams for each category

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I have 3 collections. One for Categories, one for Exams and one for Results.
Categories is like below:

```
{
  _id: 3276438964823,
  name: 'Category 1',
  companyId: 12345
}
```

Exam collection is like below:

```
{
  _id: 482348327,
  categoryId: 3276438964823,
  name: "Computer",
  companyId: 12345
}
```

Result collection is like below:

```
{
  _id: 482348327,
  exam_id: 482348327
}
```

Result i want is something like this:

```
[
  {category: 'Categori 1', exam_count: 1, exam_done: 0},
  {category: 'Categori 2', exam_count: 8, exam_done: 5},
  .....
]
```

For now i have tried this code:

```
Exams.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        companyId: { $in: 
            [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userData.companyId)] },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "categories",
        let: {
          companyid: "$companyId",
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: ["$companyId", "$$companyid"],
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: ["$type", 1],
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              name: 1,
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "categories",
      },
    },
    ])
```

What i get right now is this one:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5ee366cb3fd50f3d388493ac",
    "active": 1,
    "categoryId": "5eb640414ac4b84d944a3639",
    "name": "Test 2",
    "insertDate": "2020-06-12T11:28:11.966Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "companyId": "5f621c2461090c2f40a014d3",
    "categories": [
        {
            "_id": "5f621d3e61090c2f40a014d9",
            "name": "A1,A2,B1,B"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f621d4b61090c2f40a014db",
            "name": "C1,C"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "5f5d2eea4387a83088e6f802",
    "active": 1,
    "categoryId": "5f5cf44710cd434344b36a91",
    "name": "Test 2",
    "insertDate": "2020-09-12T20:26:18.294Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "companyId": "5f621c2461090c2f40a014d3",
    "categories": [
        {
            "_id": "5f621d3e61090c2f40a014d9",
            "name": "A1,A2,B1,B"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f621d4b61090c2f40a014db",
            "name": "C1,C"
        }
    ]
},
]
```

But this is not what i want. I want to count all exams for all categories that i have on me category collection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to count a $lookup fields in mongo db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404330/how-to-count-a-lookup-fields-in-mongo-db)

Comment: no, it doesn't anwser my question

Comment: can you add what have you tried and debugging details otherwise your question will close.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying from exams collection and lookup with categories, but it should from category and lookup with exams,

- `$lookup` with `exams` collection
- `$lookup` with `results` collection
- `$addFeilds` to get count of total exams and total results using `$size`

```
Categories.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "exams",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "categoryId",
      as: "examsCount"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "results",
      localField: "examsCount._id",
      foreignField: "exam_id",
      as: "doneExams"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      examsCount: { $size: "$examsCount" },
      doneExams: { $size: "$doneExams" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xckMYOkzSmV)

Comment: How if i want to add another condition for exams ? Because i want to have categoryId the same, but exam also should have active = 1

Comment: you can use lookup with pipeline that you have already used, just provide the condition field to your sample documents, i can not see that field in your provided sample documents

Comment: Sorry, I have also another collection that names "Result", can i add another property together with examsCount, as "doneExams". So for each exams category i want to count how for them are done. Result has exam_id as property

Comment: I want this result at the end: { category: "Test", total_exams: 20, done_exams: 10 }. This is all i except

Comment: look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xckMYOkzSmV)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kpQu5re2Dj6 I can't find my problem here

Comment: this is invalid there are many issues in your query it requires space to answer you, my suggestion is you can ask new question and just get others opinion.